# Hiding URL bar on mobile (android chrome)

Tags: javascript, css, html, semantic-ui

I have this in the `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And this after the `</head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onLoad = function() {        
      window.scrollTo(0,1);
  }
</script>
```

I am using semantic-ui. URL bar still doesn't disappear on page load. It doesn't even sometimes disappear when I scroll down. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide address bar

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // This hides the address bar:
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

But I received problems for iPhone 6 and some Nexus.

This could also be a nice approach https://github.com/scottjehl/Hide-Address-Bar/blob/master/hide-address-bar.js